# Karma/Jasmine/Phantom JS testing - SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'import'

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am attempting to incorporate karma testing. I am using angular 1.5, webpack and gulp. When I `karma start` I get the following in the terminal:

```
`18 10 2016 13:52:03.082:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
18 10 2016 13:52:03.100:WARN [karma]: Port 9876 in use
18 10 2016 13:52:03.101:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.1.2 server started at http://localhost:9877/
18 10 2016 13:52:03.101:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
18 10 2016 13:52:03.125:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
18 10 2016 13:52:06.629:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9877/
18 10 2016 13:52:06.649:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#EcTUgwnkFnvZHyN0AAAA with id 14262338
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'import'
  at Project/src/app/index.js:14`
```

I would appreciate any advice as to why I am getting this error. I am assuming it is because Phantom does not accept es6. I've tried the karma-es6-shim and a few other things without success.
Here are my files:
**karma.conf.js**

```
`var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '../',
    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],`

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      { pattern: './Project/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js'},
      { pattern: './Project/node_modules/angular/angular.js' },
      { pattern: './Project/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'},
      { pattern: './Project/src/app/index.js'},
      { pattern: './Project/src/app/Test/**/*.spec.js', watched: false}
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
      'lambda/*/*.js'
    ],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      './src/app/**/*.js': ['babel'],
      './src/app/**/index.js': ['webpack'],
      './src/app/Test/**/index.js': ['webpack'],
      './src/app/Test/**/.js': ['babel']
    },

    webpack: webpackConfig('module'),
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],

    // web server port
    //port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO.DEBUG,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    plugins: [
      require('karma-babel-preprocessor'),
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-webpack'),
      // require('karma-chrome-launcher')
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher')
    ],

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  });
};`
```

Comment: Did you solve your issue? What do you have in your webpack config?

Comment: Hi Luke, Yes we did a complete change of the karma.config file and included an index just for the karma. Took about three weeks but I'm officially testing in Karma!

Comment: What about sharing those configs? @KateS

Answer (score 2):

In webpack config file add

```
module: {
   loaders: [
     {
       test: /\.jsx?$/,
       loader: 'babel',
       exclude: /node_modules/,
     } 
   ]
 }
```

hope this solves the issue

Comment: Where to add it? If I append this code to the end of file, it says "Unnecessary label module."